# I am writing a HLA (High Level Assembly) to find the largest value. And return in AH register

Tags: assembly, hla

I am writing a HLA (High Level Assembly) to find the largest value. And return in AH register.My results keep giving me "-52" instead of the largest value, 20 in this case. I would appreciate any input to put me back on track.

```
// File: Largest
  program MainLargest;
  #include ("stdlib.hhf");

  static
    iValue1 : int8 := 1;
    iValue2 : int8 := 10;
    iValue3 : int8 := 20;
    iValue4 : int8 := 0;

  procedure largest (value1 : int8; value2 : int8; value3 : int8; value4 : int8); @nodisplay; @noframe;

  static
    iReturnAddress : dword;
    iResult : int8;
    iTemp : int16;
    iRegisterValue : dword;

  begin largest;
    mov (EBX, iRegisterValue);
    pop (iReturnAddress);
    pop (iTemp);
    
    pop (iTemp);                    // This is value4
    mov (iTemp, BX);
    mov (BL, value4);
    
    pop (iTemp);                    // This is value3
    mov (iTemp, BX);
    mov (BL, value3);
    
    pop (iTemp);                    // This is value2
    mov (iTemp, BX);
    mov (BL, value2);
    
    pop (iTemp);                    // This is value1
    mov (iTemp, BX);
    mov (BL, value1);
    
    push (iReturnAddress);
    push (iRegisterValue);
    
    mov (value1, DH);
    mov (DH , iResult);
    mov (iResult, CH);
    
    cmp (value2, CH);
    jg putInAH;
    
    cmp (value3, CH);
    jg putInAH;
    
    cmp (value4, CH);
    jg putInAH;
    jmp ExitSequence;
    
  putInAH:
    mov (CH, AH);
    jmp ExitSequence;

  ExitSequence:
    pop (EBX);
    ret();
  end largest;

  begin MainLargest;
    stdout.put ("Largest (");
    stdout.puti8 (iValue1);
    stdout.put (", ");
    stdout.puti8 (iValue2);
    stdout.put (", ");
    stdout.puti8 (iValue3);
    stdout.put (", ");
    stdout.puti8 (iValue4);
    stdout.put (") equals ");
    call largest;
    stdout.puti8 (AH);
  end MainLargest;

The result 
Largest (1, 10, 20, 0) equals -52
```

The result should be 20. Instead I am getting -52.

Here is the C++ equivalent of the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int largest (int value1, int value2, int value3, int value4) {
   int result = value1;
   if (value2 > result) {
      result = value2;
   }
   if (value3 > result) {
      result = value3;
   }
   if (value4 > result) {
      result = value4;
   }
   return result;
}

int main()
{
    int value1 = 1;
    int value2 = 10;
    int value3 = 20;
    int value4 = 0;
    
    int x = largest (value1, value2, value3, value4);
    cout << "Largest (" << value1 << "," << value2 << "," <<  value3 <<"," << value4 << ") equals " << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> call largest;
> ```

You are not passing the values to the procedure *largest*.
Check with *hla*, but it's either

```
call largest(iValue1,iValue2,iValue3,iValue4);
```

or

```
procedure largest (iValue1 : int8; iValue2 : int8; iValue3 : int8; iValue4 : int8); @nodisplay; @noframe;
```

---

Your code does not enough compares.

> ```
> cmp (value2, CH);
> jg putInAH;
>
> cmp (value3, CH);
> jg putInAH;
>
> cmp (value4, CH);
> jg putInAH;
> ```

If value2 happens to be greater than `CH` (and it does because 10 is GT 1), you still have to see if neither value3 nor value4 are greater then value2, before you can conclude that value2 is the greatest.

The C++ code has code blocks that fall through into each other and with multiple assignments to *result*, but your code just has the one assignment in *putInAH*.

---

> ```
> pop (iReturnAddress);
> pop (iTemp);
>
> pop (iTemp);                    // This is value4
> ```

Why do you need this extra `pop (iTemp)`? There should be no dword alignment issues given the dword return addresss and the 4 word arguments totalling 2 dwords.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I fixed it and it is now giving me the right result. First pop(iTemp) is to just junk to align the stack, but the second one is for the "value". For the call function "call largest;" is how HLA call the procedure. It is correct.